# How to set custom session persistence in firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am trying to achieve the following:
set my own custom time for auto log out off auth? However,
my current logic achieves only session open in only one tab, but logs me out after certain time..

```js
// L2 Set auth persistence to "session"
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    // Authentication state persistence set to "session"
    // Continue with other Firebase Authentication operations
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Comment: I documented the default behavior of the Firebase Authentication below. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit it clarify what "but logs me out after certain time" means. The best way to do that would be to show code that doesn't give you the result that you expect - for example that shows how you determine that the user is logged out after a certain time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't automatically log off users, and doesn't have any built-in mechanism for enabling something like that.

In most browser-based environments the Firebase Authentication automatically stores the credentials in local storage by default and restores them from there when the page/app is reloaded. To detect the outcome of this restore, you'll want to use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Only in non-browser environments, or browsers where the default behavior unexpectedly doesn't persist/restore the credentials, is there any need to call `setPersistence` yourself.

---

If you want to automatically log out the user after a certain interval, consider setting a timer for that in your application code and calling `signOut` as shown in the code sample [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps).

Comment: For some reason i was getting logged out I thought is firebase .. thanks for clarifying.